# Help identifying a SMPS chip

Tags: integrated-circuit, switch-mode-power-supply, identification, opto-isolator

I have an IC from ST marked as:
258
*ST* GZ151

I can not find any info about this IC.
It seems to be the driver for the voltage optocoupler. 
PS model is FSP-150RAB and it has also an L6599 and NCP1605 ICs.
I'm trying to modify the output voltage.

Any help/datasheet is welcome.

A picture of the IC in the optocoupler section:

[image: A picture of the IC]

Comment: Suspect if might be an LM258. The marking for a SOIC LM258 -40 to 105 degC is, errrr, 258.

Comment: I think @DiBosco is correct. Here (https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X0000AIc54ISQR/i-am-trying-to-find-st-micro-part-from-marking-code-given-on-it-first-line-258second-line-g6z524can-someone-help-me-to-recognize-right-part-number) is a similar question with the same answer.

Comment: Thanks  DiBosco, it make sense. I can see that one of the operationals is not used. 
I was wrong, It's not related with voltage but with current limit. It has another optocoupler drived by a SMD ¿BJT? marked A92. Need further work but now I'm in the right direction.
Thanks also Seir for the link.

Comment: @dibosco you should answer this, not in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

It's almost definitely an LM258. The marking for a SOIC LM258 -40 to 105 degC is, indeed, 258.